# Queries show data but not column names

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql

I'm getting through  [the postgresql tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/tutorial-select.html), I've created my db, 2 tables, weather and cities and added a few lines of data. 
When I query my db with this sql statement for example:

```
SELECT city, temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp, date FROM weather;
```

I should get this:

```
     city     | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date
--------------+---------+---------+------+------------
San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27
San Francisco |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29
Hayward       |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29
(3 rows)
```

but I get this:

```
San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27
San Francisco |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29
Hayward       |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29
```

I'm missing the column names for all queries. Why wouldn't psql show the column names? Do I have something to configure or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> `\t`
>
> Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count footer. This command is equivalent to `\pset tuples_only` and is provided for convenience.

Comment: Note that is `-t` as a command line argument.

Comment: any way to add it part of the query option?